# Spring override non-application.properties file in Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I use an external pure Java library that uses a file that is called `updater.properties`.
Im currently writing some Spring-Boot Integration Tests with `@SpringBootTest`.
The problem I currently have is that i don’t find any option to pass/use a different `updater.properties` file with Spring. Is there a solution for this? Or does the library need to be updated for this to work?
The `updater.properties` is in my resource folder and being parsed internally by the library.
Would be happy for any help!

Answer (score 0):

@SaltukKezer, yes you can. First step make a config class like

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/updater.properties")
public class UpdaterProperties{


     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     public String getMyPropertyValue() {
        return env.getProperty("your.property.name");
     }
  
 }
```

Then second step, just get an instance of this class and call the getters

Comment: That doesn't help me in my scenario because in the main application i have a @Configuration class that scans some extra packages based on a value in the `updater.properties` file. I want to have different test scenarios with different contents of the `updater.properties`

Comment: So it sounds like you need to read the properties file before the spring container starts?  Also send some code it's hard to see what you mean.